# Simple way to host an API that needs a .exe file on a Cloud service

Tags: deployment, api-design

I'm working on a relatively simple web application, and a part of it involves submitting chessboard data to an API for processing, evaluation, etc. For the backend processes, I have a python script which uses the Stockfish module, and it requires a Stockfish exe to run. When running it locally, I provide a path to my Stockfish exe, but I'm not sure I can do that if I will not be hosting the API publicly on my computer. What would be the best way to deploy the API so that I can access it publicly (i.e. be able to send requests to a public URL from my frontend code)? I've tried a few resources like Azure and AWS Lambda but I can't seem to figure out how to get my functions to link and use a .exe file that I upload.

I don't have much experience working with actual deployment and this is mainly just a practice project to get a feel for how to set up a full-stack application. Thank you for any help!